# How to use Ionic 4 with a core providers module, and also lazy loaded feature modules

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am porting my Ionic3 application, which has always only had the one application module to Ionic4, where I want to, as per Angular style guidelines, use a `core` module for all application wide providers. I also want all my `pages` to be lazy loaded (so have their own module), and some of these lazy loaded modules may also have providers, that are only ever used in that module.

I have created a new application, and are importing a piece at a time.

So, I have a core module where I have put most of my providers, and the module file has the following:

```
     // core.module.ts
     @NgModule({
      declarations:[],
        providers: [
          AppRuntimeStatusService,
          ConfigurationService,
          ....  etc
        ],
      imports: [
        CommonModule
      ]
    })
```

Each provider in here has the following:

```
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class AppRuntimeStatusService {
    ...
```

Though perhaps the `providedIn` is not needed/should not be used here?

So, I import this into my main app module. I have the following two module files:

```
    // app-routing.module.ts
    const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: Constants.vals.pageRoutePaths.home,
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: Constants.vals.pageRoutePaths.home,
        loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomePageModule'
      },
    ];


    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules }),   
      ],
      exports: [RouterModule]
    })

    export class AppRoutingModule {}

    // app.module.ts
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent],
      entryComponents: [],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
          loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
            deps: [HttpClient]
          }
        }),
        IonicModule.forRoot(),
        IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
        AppRoutingModule,
        CoreModule           // Singleton objects (services, components that are loaded only once, etc.)    
      ],
      providers: [
        StatusBar,
        SplashScreen,
        { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
      ],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule {}

    /**
     * This needs to be a separate function for Ionic
     * @param {Http} http - http service
     */
    export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
      return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, '../assets/i18n/', '.json');
    }
```

So, in the above, I have the following:

```
  IonicModule.forRoot(),          <---- in here or on core module, or both?
  IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),   <---- in here or on core module, or both?
  AppRoutingModule,
  CoreModule    <--- import of core
```

Finally, in one of my feature modules, (lazy loaded), I have:

```
        // home-routing.module.ts
    const routes: Routes = [
      { path: '', component: HomePage }
    ];

    @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
      exports: [RouterModule]
    })

    export class HomeRoutingModule {
      static components = [HomePage];
    }

    // home.module.ts
    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        TranslateModule.forChild(),    
        FormsModule,
        IonicModule,
        HomeRoutingModule
      ],
      providers: [AvailablePagesService],  // <--- local service only used in this module
      declarations: [HomePage, HomeRoutingModule.components]
    })
    export class HomePageModule {}
```

When I run the above, I have a call that will call a method, to show an Ionic `Toast` in one of my `core` module providers (ie `UserMessageService`).

I get the following error:

```
     core.js:15724 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[UserMessageService -> Toast]: 
      StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[UserMessageService -> Toast]: 
        NullInjectorError: No provider for Toast!
    Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[UserMessageService -> Toast]: 
      StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[UserMessageService -> Toast]: 
        NullInjectorError: No provider for Toast!
        at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (core.js:8896)
        at resolveToken (core.js:9141)
        at tryResolveToken (core.js:9085)
        at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:8982)
        at resolveToken (core.js:9141)
        at tryResolveToken (core.js:9085)
        at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:8982)
        at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:21218)
        at _createClass (core.js:21271)
        at _createProviderInstance (core.js:21235)
        at resolvePromise (zone.js:831)
        at resolvePromise (zone.js:788)
        at zone.js:892
        at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
        at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17290)
        at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
        at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
        at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:601)
```

So, I am not sure what I have wrong.

I tried moving the `IonicModule.forRoot(),` from the main application module, to the `core` module, but this did not help.

So, where does `IonicModule.forRoot()` and others (e.g. `IonicStorageModule.forRoot()`) belong?

In the

- main app module
- in the core module
- in the lazy loaded module
- some combination of the above

I have read many posts on the modules (and will lookup more), but I still have not quite got a gasp of what needs to go where.

### Update

It looks like at least some of my problem may be in trying to use the **Native plugins** in the core module.

My previous error, was to do with `Toast` which was coming from Ionic Native, ie I have

```
import { Toast as NativeToast } from '@ionic-native/toast/ngx';
```

When I removed this import, and the related code, the error went away, and the next error was to do with another Native plugin...

```
    Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AppRuntimeStatusService -> Network]: 
    core.js:15724
    message:"Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AppRuntimeStatusService -> Network]: \n  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AppRuntimeStatusService -> Network]: \n    NullInjectorError: No provider for Network!\nError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AppRuntimeStatusService -> Network]: \n  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AppRuntimeStatusService -> Network]: \n    NullInjectorError: No provider for Network!\n    at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:45019:19)\n    at resolveToken (http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:45264:24)\n    at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:45208:16)\n    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:45105:20)\n    at resolveToken (http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:45264:24)\n    at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:45208:16)\n    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInject...
```

In the above mentioned service, I have the following:

```
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network/ngx';
```

I currently only have the following in my core.module.ts:

```
imports: [    
  SharedModule,  // <-- currently only has CommonModule
  HttpClientModule    
],
```

I have both these packages installed:

```
// package.json
"cordova-plugin-network-information": "2.0.1",
"cordova-plugin-x-toast": "2.7.2",
...
```

And the associated plugins:

[image]

All of these I have been installing from scratch as per the Ionic documentation to make sure they are install into the new Ionic 4 project correctly.

So maybe it is the **Ionic plugins** that somehow need importing into the core module?

If I get the above right, then the rest of the application should follow the same pattern.

Comment: I don't want to say for sure yet (as I haven't actually called any of the code yet), but it looks like when I added the native imports (ie Network, Toast) to the core module providers array, my errors went away. I noticed in my previous Ionic 3 app I had the same thing in the one app level module, so now have added to the core instead.